# Extract year form date mysql

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa, i want to extract year from date.

```
@Query("select t from Table t where extract(year from t.date) =: date")

Set<Table> extractYear(@Param("date") Integer date);
```

But it gives me an error

```
Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.Set com.repositroy.extratYear(java.lang.Integer) but parameter 'date' not found in annotated query 'select t from Table t where extract(year from t.date) =: date'!
```

Comment: The `:` should be followed by the parameter name, yours is followed by a whitespace in the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between ":" and the parameter:

```
... "where extract(year from rec.closingDate) = :closingDate"
```